# Prime numbers yield from Pythagoras triples

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, factoring, pythagorean-triples

Pythagoras theorem $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$

we got $$P_{prime}(a,b)={a^4+b^4+(a+b)^4\over a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2}$$

Where $(a,b,c)$ are Pythagoras theorem triples, this function $P_{prime}(a,b)$ always produce a prime number for the values of a and b.

Examples: $P_{prime}(3,4)=37$, $P_{prime}(5,12)=229$, $P_{prime}(68,285)=105229$ and so on...

I have checked a lot of values, it seem to be prime so far.

My question is: **Does the function $P_{prime}(a,b)$ always produce prime numbers?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cancel common factors the fraction comes out to $$a^2+ab+b^2=c^2+ab=(a+b)^2-ab$$

Now if $a, b$ have a common factor this will certainly not be prime.

If $(a,b,c)$ is a primitive triple, then $abc$ is divisible by $60$ and the primes $2,3,5$ can't divide the expression, which is co-prime to $a,b,c$

Suppose we want $a^2+ab+b^2$ divisible by $p$. We have, modulo $p$ $$a\equiv \frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4b^2}}2=b\cdot\frac {-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}2$$so we need $-3$ to be a quadratic residue mod $p$ - for odd primes this means $p=6n+1$ (actually this should be obvious from $\omega^3=1$)

As Michael Rosenberg observes via a different route, with $a=x^2-y^2$ and $b=2xy$ the expression becomes $$x^4+2x^3y+2x^2y^2-2xy^3+y^4$$

You can investigate this modulo $p$ and should find that the smallest prime which can appear as a factor in the primitive case is $13$ - eg for $x=5, y=2, a=21, b=20$ giving $13\times 97$

$37$ is also possible (and indeed appears as one of the primes you found) and $61$.

If I had a little time I'd be checking why it is that primes $\equiv 13 \bmod 24$ seem to be turning up. Checking through further $109, 157, 181, 229$ all work.

Then we had $97$ from the example for $13$ and modulo $24$ this suggests $25, 49, 73, 97$, with the first two not prime and indeed $73$ does allow composite values.

So conjecture that the prime factors are all equivalent to $1\bmod 12$ (there are no solutions modulo $7$, for example). Since this excludes a lot of small primes it is not surprising that it is not so easy to find composite solutions.

---

To give some examples:

For $p=13$ we have

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} x & y & a & b & a^2+ab+b^2 & (a^2+ab+b^2)/p\\4& 3& 7& 24 &793 &61\\
5 &2 &21 &20 &1261& 97\\
5 &4 &9 &40& 2041& 157\\
6 &5 &11 &60 &4381& 337\\
7 &2 &45 &28& 4069& 313\\
8 &3 &55 &48& 7969& 613\\
9 &2 &77 &36& 9997& 769\\
10 &1 &99 &20& 12181& 937\\
10 &7 &51 &140& 29341& 2257\\
12 &7 &95 &168& 53209& 4093\\
14 &3 &187 &84 &57733 &4441\\
15 &4 &209 &120 &83161 &6397\\
16 &5 &231 &160 &115921 &8917\\
17 &8 &225 &272 &185809 &14293 \end{array}$$

For $p=37$ we have

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} x & y & a & b & a^2+ab+b^2 & (a^2+ab+b^2)/p\\10&7&51&140&29341&793\\
11&4&105&88&28009&757\\
12&1&143&24&24457&661\\
14&9&115&252&105709&2857\\
16&5&231&160&115921&3133\\
18&1&323&36&117253&3169 \end{array}$$

$p=61$ gives
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} x & y & a & b & a^2+ab+b^2 & (a^2+ab+b^2)/p\\
4&3&7&24&793&13\\
8&5&39&80&11041&181\\
10&7&51&140&29341&481\\
23&2&525&92&332389&5449
 \end{array}$$
For $p=73$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} x & y & a & b & a^2+ab+b^2 & (a^2+ab+b^2)/p\\
9&4&65&72&14089&193\\
13&10&69&260&90301&1237\\
14&5&171&140&72781&997\\
19&12&217&456&353977&4849\\
 \end{array}$$
For $p=97$
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|} x & y & a & b & a^2+ab+b^2 & (a^2+ab+b^2)/p\\
5&2&21&20&1261&13\\
13&2&165&52&38509&397\\
17&6&253&204&157237&1621\\
37&2&1365&148&2087149&21517\\
 \end{array}$$

---

To go back to the analysis we have, modulo $p$, $a=\omega b$ where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ and $\omega^3 =1$.

We want $x^2-y^2=2\omega xy$ whence $x^2-2\omega xy-y^2=0$ and $$x=y\cdot \left(\omega \pm \sqrt {\omega^2+1} \right) = y\cdot \left(\omega \pm \omega \sqrt {\omega+1} \right)=y\cdot\left(\omega \pm \omega^2\sqrt {-1} \right)$$

Hence we need $-1$ to be a square $\bmod p$ ie $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and since we already have $p\equiv 1 \bmod 6$ we must have $p\equiv 1 \bmod 12$.

---

Observe also that the numbers in the final column can only have prime factors $\equiv 1 \bmod 12$ ie $13, 37, 61, 73, 97$ so it is very easy to test whether these are prime.

---

Further note with $x=10, y=7$ we have $a=51, b=140, a^2+ab+b^2= 13\times 37 \times 61= 29341$

$x=23, y=20$ gives $13^2\times 37 \times 157$

$x=49, y=4$ gives $6776809=13\times 37 \times 73 \times 193$

$x=124, y=99, 13\times 37\times 61 \times 109 \times 241$

See my other answer for data which would enable the Chinese Remainder Theorem to be used to obtain arbitrary numbers of prime factors.

Comment: Nice work, Mark! +1

Answer (score 6):

Let $a=2xy,$ and $b=x^2-y^2$.

Hence, we obtain:
$$\frac{(2xy)^4+(x^2-y^2)^4+(2xy+x^2-y^2)^4}{(2xy)^2+(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy+x^2-y^2)^2}=x^4+y^4+2x^3y-2xy^3+2x^2y^2.$$
We can get this expression by the following.
$$\frac{a^4+b^4+(a+b)^4}{a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2}=\frac{2(a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4)}{2(a^2+ab+b^2)}=$$
$$=\frac{(a^2+ab+b^2)^2}{a^2+ab+b^2}=a^2+ab+b^2=x^4+y^4+2x^3y-2xy^3+2x^2y^2.$$

Now, easy to find a counterexample: $x=10$ and $y=1$, which gives $a=20$ and $b=99.$

Answer (score 2):

$P_{prime}(6,8)=148$ is not prime

$P_{prime}(7,24)=793=13\cdot61$ so it doesn't hold even for primitive triples

Comment: it is false I just found a few also

Comment: Could it be that it is only false for non-primitive pythagorean triples? Such as (6, 8, 10).

Comment: $P_{prime}(65,72)=14089=73\times 193$

Answer (score 0):

This is a more abstract take on my computational answer.

The fraction cancels out to $a^2+ab+b^2$.

Now suppose that we have a prime $p=12n+1$. Modulo $p$ the multiplicative group is cyclic of order $12n$. We work modulo $p$, so we can find $w$ and $t$ with $w^3=1, w\neq 1$ and $t^2=-1$.

Now choose $y$ and let $x=(w+w^2t)y$

If we now set $a=x^2-y^2=(w^2+2t-w-1)y^2=2w^2(1+wt)y^2$ and $b=2xy=2w(1+wt)y^2$ whence $a=wb$ and we have $$a^2+ab+b^2=b^2(1+w+w^2)=0$$So we have solved the congruence modulo $p$.

We can choose $\pm t$ and $w$ or $w^2$ for this construction, but once selected they give an infinite family of solutions modulo $p$. These grow indefinitely, and since divisible by $p$ the larger ones are not prime.

---

As an example, for $p=13$ we have $5^2\equiv-1$ and $3^3\equiv 1$.

Choose $y=1$ to give $x=3+45\equiv-4$ and $a=15, b=-8$ which gives a value of $169$.

We could also choose $y=1, x=9$ (we can choose equivalents modulo $13$) to give $a=80, b=18$

Choosing $y=2$ gives $x=2\times -4\equiv5$ and this gives $a=21, b=20$ giving $1261=13 \times 97$ and again we can choose any representatives of the residue classes for $x$ and $y$ giving an infinite family of solutions.

---

Note that this can be written in terms of a primitive twelfth root of unity modulo $p$ as $x=(u-u^2)y$ with $a=2u^3(u-1)y^2, b=2u(1-u)y^2$. Since there are four such roots $(u, u^5, u^7, u^{11})$, this encompasses the four choices which could be made above.

Comment: See my other answer to see where $x=(w+w^2t)y$ comes from.